# How to get the incoming number of caller?

Tags: android, cordova

I need to receive the **phone number** of the caller in a **cordova**, its okay that it will be just in android. I found this plugin:
https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap

This plugin **works**, however not emitting the phone number - only the state of the dial.
I have digging in the src of the plugin I have seen this:

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

    ... code 
}
```

As you can see there `**incomingNumber**` but it's **null** (tested on real device, and answered a call).

I have tried to add this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

How to make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Create one Java class named PhoneStateReceiver and it should extend BroadcastReceiver class.

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

PhoneStateReceiver class :

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the imports and the link to the cordova parts? What is Toast for example? BroadcasterReceiver shouldnt be imported as well?

Comment: Broadcast receiver is one of the component of android. You just create a class and paste this code. It will work, and ask for import itself, if you are using android studio.

Comment: Thats okay I just need the code of the java not the full implementation of cordova, I dont want to waste your time I will try doing it bymyself